# Как сделать так, чтобы в методе можно было вводить неограниченное кол-во аргументов?

Tags: java, методы, параметры, varargs

Как сделать так, чтобы в методе можно было вводить неограниченное кол-во аргументов?

Comment: как-то так `Type... arg`

Answer (score 6):

**varargs** *(сокращение от variable-length arguments)* - список аргументов перемен­ной длины) - средство, которое позволило изба­виться от явного формирования массива аргументов перед вызовом метода.

> Соответствующие методы называют методами с переменным числом
>   аргу­ментов (другое название - методы переменной арности). В методах
>   этого типа список параметров имеет не фиксированную, а переменную
>   длину, что обеспечивает дополни­тельную гибкость, позволяя методам
>   принимать произвольное число аргументов.

Пример использования:

---

```
// Метод vaTest() с переменным числом аргументов
// Объявление метода со списком аргументов переменной длины

static void vaTest(int ... v) {
    System.out.println("Число аргументов: " + v.length);
    System.out.println("Содержимое: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" arg " + i + ": " + v[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Примечание:* так как `varargs` представляет собой [синтаксический сахар](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80), то накладываются также ограничения при использовании.

1) Аргумент, который получает `...` должен быть последним в сигнатуре метода.
Если можно написать  `myMethod (int i, String ... strings)`, то так `myMethod (String ... string, int i)` нет.

2) Список параметров переменной длины можно указать в методе только один раз.

```
int doIt(int a, int b, double c, int ... vals, double ... morevals) {
    // Ошибка
}
```

Более подробно можете почитать [здесь](http://pro-java.ru/java-dlya-nachinayushhix/peremennoe-chislo-argumentov-metodov-yazyka-java/).

[Офф. документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Здравствуйте, отличная информация! Но почему то у меня при запуске вылетает [Ljava.lang.String;@4554617c. Вот сам метод: public static void out(String... strings){

        System.out.print(strings);

    }

Comment: @Sharper555, здравствуйте. Когда Вы пишите `System.out.println(object)`, вызывается метод `toString()`, который выводит строку, состоящую из имени класса, символа и хэш-кода объекта в шестнадцатеричном формате. Чтобы этого избежать можно [переопределить метод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/8370915) `toString`.

Comment: @invzbl3 Стоит дополнить ответ тем, что указанная возможно являет собой исключительно синтаксический сахар, и ,по факту, в java количество аргументов функции должно быть строго фиксировано.