# В чем отличие троеточия от квадратных скобок?

Tags: java, методы, varargs

В чем разница между

```
private void onProgressUpdate(String... item);
```

и

```
private void onProgressUpdate(String[] item);
```

Comment: Передача неограниченного кол-ва элементов и передача массива фиксированной длинны, а так же в первом варианте имеется возможность использовать дженерики P.S. поправьте если имеются неточности

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать так, чтобы в методе можно было вводить неограниченное кол-во аргументов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865617/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Главное отличие в сигнатуре методов. В первом случае сигнатура метода определяет один или более параметров типа `String`, во втором  передается только один параметр типа `String[]`. Определение `vararg` также допускает использование массива в качестве аргумента.

В первом случае может быть использовано

```
onProgressUpdate("item1","item2","item3");
```

или

```
onProgressUpdate(new String[]{"item1","item2","item3"});
```

а во втором случае только последний вариант.

---

Более подробно об `vararg` можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 7):

Первое, это `varargs`, что обозначает передачу неограниченного количества элементов. Пример: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/)

```
void func(int... numbers);
func(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Второй, это просто передача массива. Пример:

```
void func(int[] arr);
int[] arr = new int[10];
func(arr);
```